# Using Sequelize and DataTypes for data types

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I've previously used a recipe for model definitions very similar to [the one from Sequelize documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/1.7.0/articles/express/#modelsindexjs), where model definitions are wrapped with factory functions to be fed to [`sequelize.import`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#importpath-model):

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  return sequelize.define('SomeModel', {
    field: DataTypes.STRING(100)
  });
};
```

This structure works for me but it is not always convenient to export wrapper function from  the module (e.g. when it exports a class for base model that uses `DataTypes` but shouldn't be imported with `sequelize.import`).

Is `Sequelize` fully interchangeable with `DataTypes` for data types (`DataTypes.STRING` vs `Sequelize.STRING`), so factory function could be omitted?

Can `DataTypes` be dependent on the dialect that was chosen in `sequelize` instance, and thus preferred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes Sequelize fully interchangeable with DataTypes for data types.

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/3e5b8772ef75169685fc96024366bca9958fee63/lib/sequelize.js

Also datatypes are mapped according to dialect but they are added to Sequelize class so you can use either

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/3e5b8772ef75169685fc96024366bca9958fee63/lib/data-types.js#L57

Comment: Thanks. That's what I suspected.